# Unable to start Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

unable to Jmeter in distribution load, getting below error please help am using jmter v3.0.20160606
Changing to JMeter home directory
Could not find ApacheJmetercore.jar
Trying JMETERHOME=
Found ApacheJMeter_core.jar

Comment: unable to Jmeter in distribution load, getting below error.. please help.. am using jmter v3.0.20160606
Changing to JMeter home directory
Could not find ApacheJmetercore.jar ...
... Trying JMETERHOME=..
Found ApacheJMeter_core.jar
Writing log file to: d:\Performance\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\jmeter
Created remote object: UnicastServerRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[10.
local),objID:[5c28f590:160bb045cbd:-7fff, 7208165816152457764]]]

Comment: please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected and normal, now you need to launch a JMeter Master like:

```
jmeter -R xxxxx -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

Replace `xxxxx` with IP address or hostname of the machine where you launched Slave node, you should see something like:

```
Starting the test on host xxxxx @ current date and time
```

More information:

- [Remote Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)
- [JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf)

---

The first of [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) is **Always use latest version of JMeter** so consider upgrading to JMeter 3.3 (current version) or whatever will be available at [JMeter Downloads](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page on next available opportunity